# Scaling with Server Side Events

Tags: http, push-notification, server-side, scaling

Consider this:

- Many clients connect to an http server
- The server is a group of nodes (i.e. Node A, Node B, etc) behind a load balancer
- A client subscribes to an event stream using server-side-events (e.g. `GET /event-stream`) and gets connected to Node A
- The same client schedules a job (e.g. `POST /prepare-zip`) that is a heavy process and needs to be handled asynchronously. This request happens to land with Node B randomly
- Once Node B finishes, we would like to notify the client - but only Node A can do it as it is maintaining the connection with the client.

How do we do that?

- Do we **broadcast from Node B to all other nodes** hoping that the relevant node will pick it up? If we use a queue for broadcasting, then all the nodes will be polling for it (including Node B) and most will reject the messages because it is only meant for Node A. Also, it seems like we are mixing responsibilities i.e. serving http requests, and processing events in the queue.
- Do we keep track of the the active connections in a shared store/db e.g. so that we can notify the relevant server?

Seems like there should be an elegant solution that I am missing?